# I need to drop unnamed: level_0 headers and other column headers in that row in this output and for the column headers to be the row directly below

Tags: python, data-science, screen-scraping

## screen scrape

```
    `url = 'https://www.pro-football- 
    reference.com/teams/buf/2020/gamelog/'
    BuffaloBillsO = pd.read_html(url)[0]`
```

## renaming the unnamed level 1's

`BuffaloBillsO.rename(columns={'Unnamed: 4_level_1': 'W/L'}, inplace=True)`

```
BuffaloBillsO.rename(columns={'Unnamed: 3_level_1': 'Box_link'}, inplace=True)

BuffaloBillsO.rename(columns={'Unnamed: 6_level_1': '@'}, inplace=True)

BuffaloBillsO.rename(columns={'Unnamed: 3_level_1': 'Box_link'}, inplace=True)
```

**strong text**

I have tried variations of the following solution but it replaces first two row and turns the first row of data into the column headers:

```
BuffaloBillsO.columns = BuffaloBillsO.iloc[0]  
BuffaloBillsO=BuffaloBillsO[1:]
BuffaloBillsO.rename_axis(columns=None).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: Can you be a little more specific with your question? like do you want to drop all the columns that contain "level_0"?

Comment: Yes all columns that contain level 0 as well as the other column titles in that row. One is 'passing' another is 'rushing ' and so on.

Comment: If you run the code and view entire table you will be able to see what i mean

Comment: Just to be clear, 
( 'Unnamed: 0_level_0',               'Week'),
 ( 'Unnamed: 1_level_0',                'Day'),
 ( 'Unnamed: 2_level_0',               'Date')

should be just 'Week','Day','Date'

Comment: Yes that is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I tried this and its working well

```
ncols=[]
for i in range(len(BuffaloBillsO.columns)):
    ncols.append(BuffaloBillsO.columns[i][1])
ncols=dict(zip(BuffaloBillsO.columns,ncols))
BuffaloBillsO.columns =BuffaloBillsO.columns.to_series().map(ncols)
```

Following was the output for BuffaloBillsO.columns

```
Index(['Week', 'Day', 'Date', 'Unnamed: 3_level_1', 'Unnamed: 4_level_1', 'OT',
       'Unnamed: 6_level_1', 'Opp', 'Tm', 'Opp', 'Cmp', 'Att', 'Yds', 'TD',
       'Int', 'Sk', 'Yds.1', 'Y/A', 'NY/A', 'Cmp%', 'Rate', 'Att', 'Yds',
       'Y/A', 'TD', 'FGM', 'FGA', 'XPM', 'XPA', 'Pnt', 'Yds', '3DConv',
       '3DAtt', '4DConv', '4DAtt', 'ToP'],
      dtype='object')
```

Comment: Welcome! kindly accept this as an answer and up vote if it worked for you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass in the headers level with `.read_html()`:

```
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.pro-football-reference.com/teams/buf/2020/gamelog/'
BuffaloBillsO = pd.read_html(url,header=1)[0]
```

**Output:**

```
print(BuffaloBillsO.columns)
Index(['Week', 'Day', 'Date', 'Unnamed: 3', 'Unnamed: 4', 'OT', 'Unnamed: 6',
       'Opp', 'Tm', 'Opp.1', 'Cmp', 'Att', 'Yds', 'TD', 'Int', 'Sk', 'Yds.1',
       'Y/A', 'NY/A', 'Cmp%', 'Rate', 'Att.1', 'Yds.2', 'Y/A.1', 'TD.1', 'FGM',
       'FGA', 'XPM', 'XPA', 'Pnt', 'Yds.3', '3DConv', '3DAtt', '4DConv',
       '4DAtt', 'ToP'],
      dtype='object')
```